# Owl Carousel: How to change size of fourth item

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'll start with a picture to further show what I mean by changing the size of the fourth `.item` class :

[How the final carousel should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAV4N.png)

This is the half working code I currently have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <!-- head -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta name="description" content="Basic usage demo">
  <meta name="author" content="David Deutsch">
  <title>
    Basic Demo | Owl Carousel | 2.3.4
  </title>

  <!-- Stylesheets -->
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,400italic,300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/docs.theme.min.css">

  <!-- Owl Stylesheets -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">

  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

  <!-- Favicons -->
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../assets/ico/favicon.png">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">

  <!-- Yeah i know js should not be in header. Its required for demos.-->

  <!-- javascript -->
  <script src="../assets/vendors/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>

</head>

<body onload="SizeChange()">
  <!--  Demos -->
  <section id="demos">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-12 columns">
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
          <div class="item">
            <h4>1</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <h4>2</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <h4>3</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <h4>4</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <h4>5</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <h4>6</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <h4>7</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <h4>8</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <h4>9</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <h4>10</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <h4>11</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <h4>12</h4>
          </div>
        </div>


        <script>
          //script
          $(document).ready(function () {
            var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
            owl.owlCarousel({
              margin: 10,
              nav: true,
              loop: true,
              responsive: {
                0: {
                  items: 1
                },
                600: {
                  items: 3
                },
                1000: {
                  items: 5
                }
              }
            })
          })

          $(window).click(SizeChange)
          function SizeChange(){
            let ActiveDivs = []
            $("div").filter(".active").each(function (index, value) {
              ActiveDivs.push(value)
            })
            let lengthOfArray = ActiveDivs.length-2
            $(ActiveDivs).find('.item').animate({"height":"150px"}, 100);
            $(ActiveDivs[lengthOfArray]).find('.item').animate({"height":"300px"}, 100);
          }

          //End script
        </script>
        <!-- vendors -->
        <script src="../assets/vendors/highlight.js"></script>
        <script src="../assets/js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

So what I did was take the divs with the `.active` class (there are 5 at a time), taking the fourth div and adding CSS to it, by that making only the fourth one bigger.

Making the fourth div in the carousel to change the height on page load and on any interaction with the carousel is what I want it to do.

Hope I got it clear enough, first post on Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The Final Result

---

The goal was to create a Netflix styled carousel with Owl carousel and so I did. 
Here is a picture for reference:

[Netflix Carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZ6Ac.png)

### The Code

---

I worked in 'OwlCarousel2-2.3.4/docs/demos/basic', copy and paste it there, and you should be fine

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta name="description" content="Basic usage demo">
  <meta name="author" content="David Deutsch">
  <title>Basic Demo | Owl Carousel | 2.3.4</title>
  <!-- Stylesheets -->
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,400italic,300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/docs.theme.min.css">
  <!-- Owl Stylesheets -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  <!-- Favicons -->
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../assets/ico/favicon.png">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script src="../assets/vendors/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


  <style>
    .item {
      background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 000) !important;
      width: 200px !important;
      padding: 0px !important;

    }

    .wraper {
      height: 500px !important;
      display: flex !important;
      align-items: center !important;
    }

    .big {
      width: 250px !important;
      -webkit-transition: width 300ms;
      -moz-transition: width 300ms;
      -ms-transition: width 300ms;
      -o-transition: width 300ms;
      transition: width 300ms;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <section id="demos">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-12 columns" style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
          <div class="item">
            <img src="/docs/demos/Moonlight_poster.jpeg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="/docs/demos/Moonlight_poster.jpeg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="/docs/demos/Moonlight_poster.jpeg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="/docs/demos/Moonlight_poster.jpeg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="/docs/demos/Moonlight_poster.jpeg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="/docs/demos/Moonlight_poster.jpeg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="/docs/demos/Moonlight_poster.jpeg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="/docs/demos/Moonlight_poster.jpeg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="/docs/demos/Moonlight_poster.jpeg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="/docs/demos/Moonlight_poster.jpeg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="/docs/demos/Moonlight_poster.jpeg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="/docs/demos/Moonlight_poster.jpeg" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>


  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
      owl.owlCarousel({
        //When page load (i think) call function 'inlargItem'
        onInitialized: inlargItem,
        autoWidth: true,
        margin: 10,
        nav: true,
        navSpeed: 700,
        loop: true,
        dots: true,
        responsive: {
          0: {
            items: 1
          },
          600: {
            items: 3
          },
          1000: {
            items: 5
          }
        }
      })
      $('.owl-stage').addClass('wraper')
    })

    //Calls inlargItem on every change
    $('.owl-carousel').on('changed.owl.carousel', function (event) {
      inlargItem(event)
    })

    //For key movement
    $(document.documentElement).keyup(function (event) {
      if (event.keyCode == 37) {
        /*left key*/
        $('.owl-carousel').trigger('prev.owl.carousel', [700]);
      } else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
        /*right key*/
        $('.owl-carousel').trigger('next.owl.carousel', [700]);
      }
    });

    //Select the forth element and add the class 'big' to it 
    function inlargItem(event) {
      //Find all 'active' class and dvide them by two 
      //5 (on larg screens) avtive classes / 2 = 2.5 
      //Math.ceil(2.5) = 3
      var activeClassDividedByTwo = Math.ceil($(".active").length / 2)
      //Adding the activeClassDividedByTwo (is 3 on larg screens)
      let OwlNumber = event.item.index + activeClassDividedByTwo
      //Rmove any 'big' class 
      $(".item").removeClass("big")
      //Adding new 'big' class to the fourth .item
      $(".item").eq(OwlNumber).addClass("big")
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

### The End Reasult

---

[Netflix styled carousel with Owl carousel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uUQ-lWrfEmc&feature=youtu.be)

Answer (score 0):

owlCarousel has [events](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html) you can use to track movement.

So basically you have to track `next.owl.carousel` or `prev.owl.carousel` and update your `SizeChange()` function by adding or subtracting one to your current highlighted div position.

Edit: events even pass Information in the event.object. The current active Item is stored in `event.item.index`.

Comment: tried this: 

`owl.on("next.owl.carousel", function (event) { console.log(event.item.index); });` 

but it didn't work

Comment: Have you defined `owl` beforehand? `var owl = $('.owl-carousel');`

Answer (score 0):

**Finally solved it!** 

Thanks for the help, love this website :D 
I know its not groundbreaking, but it feels like a huge success to me :D

What I was trying to do is taking the fourth `.item` in the carousel and change the CSS of it. 
By that getting closer to a result looking like this:

### [Crousel Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXX6D.png)

### The Code

---

I worked in 'OwlCarousel2-2.3.4/docs/demos/basic', copy and paste it there, and you should be fine

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta name="description" content="Basic usage demo">
  <meta name="author" content="David Deutsch">
  <title>Basic Demo | Owl Carousel | 2.3.4</title>
  <!-- Stylesheets -->
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,400italic,300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/docs.theme.min.css">
  <!-- Owl Stylesheets -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  <!-- Favicons -->
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../assets/ico/favicon.png">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script src="../assets/vendors/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>

  <style>
    .big {
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <section id="demos">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-12 columns">
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
          <div class="item">
            <h4>1</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <h4>2</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <h4>3</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <h4>4</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <h4>5</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <h4>6</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <h4>7</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <h4>8</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <h4>9</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <h4>10</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <h4>11</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <h4>12</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>


  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
      owl.owlCarousel({
        //When draging the carousel call function 'callback'
        onDragged: callback,
        //When page load (i think) call function 'callback'
        onInitialized: callback,
        margin: 20,
        nav: false,
        loop: true,
        dots: false,
        responsive: {
          0: {
            items: 1
          },
          600: {
            items: 3
          },
          1000: {
            items: 5
          }
        }
      })
    })

    //Select the forth element and add the class 'big' to it 
    function callback(event) {
      //Find all 'active' class and dvide them by two 
      //5 (on larg screens) avtive classes / 2 = 2.5 
      //Math.ceil(2.5) = 3
      var activeClassDividedByTwo = Math.ceil($(".active").length / 2)
      //Adding the activeClassDividedByTwo (is 3 on larg screens)
      let OwlNumber = event.item.index + activeClassDividedByTwo
      console.log(OwlNumber)
      //Rmove any 'big' class 
      $(".item").removeClass('big')
      //Adding new 'big' class to the fourth .item
      $(".item").eq(OwlNumber).addClass('big')
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### How I Did It

---

Inside Owl initialiser

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
  owl.owlCarousel({
```

add

`onInitialized: callback,
onDragged: callback,`

This calls a function called 'callback' when you drag the carousel and when the page loads.

This is the function 'callback' :

```
   function callback(event) {
      //Find all 'active' class and dvide them by two 
      //5 (on larg screens) avtive classes / 2 = 2.5 
      //Math.ceil(2.5) = 3
      var activeClassDividedByTwo = Math.ceil($(".active").length / 2)
      //Adding the activeClassDividedByTwo (is 3 on larg screens)
      let OwlNumber = event.item.index + activeClassDividedByTwo
      console.log(OwlNumber)
      //Rmove any 'big' class 
      $(".item").removeClass('big')
      //Adding new 'big' class to the fourth .item
      $(".item").eq(OwlNumber).addClass('big')
    }
```

As I wrote in the notes inside the function,
 It first finds all `.active` classes (for this example there will be 5 `.active` classes ) 
 Then it takes all the `.active` classes divide them by 2, 
 By using `Math.ceil()` we get the number 3.
 Then we add this varuble we got to the `event.item.index` (`event.item.index` gives us the current active `.item`, for me it was the first one)
Now we can target the `.item` we wanted (fourth one)
By using `$(".item").eq(OwlNumber).addClass('big')`, I added a class called `.big` to the fourth **active** `.item` class.

---

Thanks again for the help!
Hope this will help somebody to :D