# Owl Carousel | How To Change Size Of .Item Using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good morning evening or afternoon,
Not too long ago I made some code that takes the fourth `.item` of the carousel and gives it a new class.
[Owl Carousel: How to change the size of the fourth item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54503936/owl-carousel-how-to-change-size-of-fourth-item/54514080#54514080)

Now I'm trying to make the selected `.item` bigger than the rest and centered using CSS with no luck.
This is the reference I'm working with :

**Reference Design**:

[image: Regrence Design]

```
I've tried using `display: flex` and `flex-grow:1`<br>
and `position:relative` `position:absolute` too.
```

any idea on how to tackle this?
Thanks :D

Comment: Never heard of `position absoulot` or `position reletive`

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed it just now :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.your-item {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

should fix your problem. Obviously, you want to change scale factor from `1.1` to whatever makes sense for your example.
If you want the transform origin to be at the bottom, use `transform-origin: 50% 100%;`